# ERROR: Content Element type "templavoila_pi1" has no rendering definition

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I had an issue with CSS styled content on my typo3 site. This is why I disabled CSC, enabled it again and included the static template.
However now I am getting the error message: "ERROR: Content Element type "templavoila_pi1" has no rendering definition!"
I found out that the error message does only appear when I am using flexible content elements. On pages without flexible content elements there is no errow message...
This is the site: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/home.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed TemplaVoila again (without uninstalling) and now it works...

Comment: Then it wasn't installed, just imported :-).

Comment: I had it working already since a long time. It just stopped working when I played around with CSC. But still there is no static template for TemplaVoila in typo3 6.0 and Templavoila 1.8.0 but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not CSC, it's TemplaVoilà. It seems as if the static template of TemplaVoila is not included or the ordering is wrong. It should be:

- CSS Styled Content
- (Static Info Tables)
- TemplaVoilà

Please check this in your root TS template.

Comment: Uhm... good point... But there is no TemplaVoila template. Not in selected templates and not in available templates... What is wrong here?

Comment: If the extension is installed (is it?), the static template must be there.

Comment: It is installed but there is no template. What happens when I uninstall and reinstall the extension? Do I loose any content or template? Do I have to safe those first somehow?